# Alternative for eval() -PHP

Tags: php, eval

i am trying to implement URL mapping in PHP. I have a json file which stores the url and functions which is to execute when that link is requested. I was using `eval()` but then i came across this

> Kepp the following Quote in mind:
>
> If eval() is the answer, you're almost certainly asking the wrong
>   question. -- Rasmus Lerdorf, BDFL of PHP

now i am thinking is their any other(better) way to do it.

My json file looks like this.

```
{
    "bw/":"main()",
    "bw/login":"login()"

}
```

and my loadPage function look like this.

```
function loadPage($url){ //$url = 'bw/'
    $str = file_get_contents('urls.json');
    $this->link = json_decode($str, true);
    $url = ltrim($url,"/");
    $key = $this->link[$url];
    eval("$key;");
}
```

**EDIT:**
i defined $this->link in my code

Comment: What's in `$this->link`?

Comment: i added $this->link in the code it was in my constructor function

Comment: "If eval() is the answer, you're almost certainly asking the wrong question." Don't put arbitrary function calls in a json file.

Answer (score 1):

A slight tweak to your JSON to allow you to call the function dynamically would make it easier, just remove the brackets so it would look like...

```
{
    "bw/":"main",
    "bw/login":"login"

}
```

and then call it using...

```
function loadPage($url){ //$url = 'bw/'
    $url = ltrim($url,"/");
    $key = $this->link[$url];
    $key();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A little better way is changing eval() to:

```
if (function_exists($key)) { 
   return $key(); 
} 
return default();
```

and you might create a function "default" to show an error 404 or default page when function doesn't exists.